Fixed-sample size sequential ANOVA or t-test
I have an experiment of fixed sample size where units (20 in each of 2 or 3 arms) are allowed to grow over time. I wish to stop the experiment as soon as there's enough evidence that the arms do not grow at the same rate.
I was thinking of measuring the size of the units every hour. I can assume that the sizes of the units in a given arm are normally distributed, with the same variance across the arms.
This sounds like a case for Wald's Sequential Probability Ratio Test, except that I'm not accumulating new units.
I've looked at methods to carry out sequential ANOVA tests like Sequential Analysis of Variance: Increasing Efficiency of Hypothesis Testing , but all the papers I've looked at assume I'm adding new units to the experiment.
I've tried evaluating the likelihood ratio of two nested linear models, one with a term for the arms and one without (e.g. with just the intercept) but it's not clear what the thresholds should be. Also, since the likelihood ratio of two nested models can never be less than 1, this test is not guaranteed to terminate.
Here's what some of the data looks like:

Edit
I think I need to apply something called repeated-measures ANOVA, but I'm not clear on how to apply it here, nor how do apply it sequentially (i.e., stop testing once a conclusion has been reached).
